# Why on android, ptrace() function doesn't have PT_DENY_ATTACH variable

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

on iOS,You can use ptrace(PT_DENY_ATTACH,0,0,0) to prevent the debugger from attaching.
However, can not find PT_DENY_ATTACH on Android

Comment: Well, iOS is not Linux. In any case you can simply ptrace yourself to deny other processes from ptracing you, since only one tracer at a time is allowed.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yes, Thanks for reminding, and I found that linux does not include PT_DENY_ATTACH.

Comment: Yep that is not present on Linux. You could also do `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);` and if that returns `-1` (meaning that some other process is already tracing you) then you can `exit(1)` to refuse being traced. Of course, this is not as powerful as actually denying tracing because the tracer could very well inrercept the syscall, change its return value and make the tracee continue anyway.